# Allow users to create a new table but one table for each topic only

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I am trying to create something where the user can create a table for a topic, but only one topic table and in that topic table other users will be able to add to that topic table.

I need the topic table to be only created once. So for ex:

User A creates a a new topic which is a new table about oranges.

Then other users will be able to add to that oranges table, but **no** other users can create another table called oranges.

How should I approach this matter?

What is the code for letting the users create the table but **only once**?

Also how safe is it to give the users the ability to create tables?

Here is some code I have that lets users add and displays data from the database.

```
    <?php
    include 'connection.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM people";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    While($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<h3>" . $person['Name'] . "</h3>";
        echo "<p>" . $person['Description'] . "</p>";
        echo "<a href=\"modify.php?id=" . $person['ID']. "\">Modify User</a>";
        echo "<span> </span>";
        echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $person['ID']. "\">Delete User</a>";
    }
?>
<h1>Create a User</h1>
<form action="create.php" method="post">
    Name<input type ="text" name="inputName" value="" /><br />
    Description<input type ="text" name="inputDesc" value="" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

You advice will be great help!

Comment: Just use a single table. I'm not sure why you think you want to do it this way, but it's a poor approach in this scenario for at least a half-dozen reasons.

Comment: Yah agreed you don't want to end up having 100 tables that you're joining together, you should try to approach the problem differently, see the database as something that has a structure that will be static and the data within it will be dynamic.  You should be writing DDL as a developer of the database not having that kind of thing happening dynamically (there may be exceptions but this is generally true), DML which is your basic CRUD insert select update delete should be used to modify the data.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to let the user create table only once :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orange` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if table exists before creating each tables. Also when you create tables, make sure to escape the string (table name) and make it lower case. You should always check table existence after converting the string (table name) like this.

You may search in Google to know more about checking table existence etc.